# Устанавить Laravel на ubuntu-сервере посредством Vagrant?

Tags: laravel5, vagrant

Всем привет!

Создал новый хостинг на  Digital Ocean  (ubuntu 16 with Apache/2.4.18, PHP Version 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 )
Через git загрузил проект Laravel 5.5.32

При запуске на сервере :

```
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/box-booking# php artisan --version
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/box-booking/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/box-booking/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/box-booking/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/box-booking/artisan on line 18
```

Читаю тут https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/deployment

И :

```
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/box-booking# composer install --optimize-autoloader
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.6.0].
    - doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/cache v1.7.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.7.1].
    - doctrine/cache v1.7.1 requires php ~7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  ...
```

В корне проекта нашел Vagrantfile :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
  ...
end
```

и понимаю что мне нужно настроить Vagrantfile и гуглом нахожу ряд ссылок: 
https://github.com/oanhnn/deployer-example/blob/master/docs/run-deployer-on-homestead.md
и в ней нахожу :

> Make Homestead.yaml and Vagrantfile by command: $
>   ./vendor/bin/homestead make Two files Homestead.yaml and Vagrantfile
>   are created in root directory of project. Edit your Homestead.yaml
>   file like:

Файла Homestead.yaml у меня в проекте нет

и вторая ссылка
https://github.com/MiniCodeMonkey/Vagrant-Laravel-Stack
Это то что мне нужно ?
Ткните плиз в каком направлении двигаться и правильную инструкции как по установке Vagrant так и deployment - по возможности подробнее...

PS:
Проверил свободное место на диске :

```
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/box-booking# df -HT   
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  513M     0  513M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     105M  5.9M   99M   6% /run
/dev/vda1      ext4       26G  1.8G   25G   7% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     521M     0  521M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     521M     0  521M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15     vfat      110M  3.6M  106M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     105M     0  105M   0% /run/user/0
```

513M этого достаточно для установки всех пакетов и развертывания приложения ?
Это dev сайт - минимальные данные для тестирования - никаких картинок/документов на аплоаде ...

Спасибо!

Comment: Появилась мысль поднять php до 7.1 Возможно это будет проще ? А как ?

Comment: УУспешно поднял php до 7.1
У меня проект в /var/www/html/box-booking
1) Напомните плиз где нужно прописать путь(вроде параметр DocumentRoot) к /var/www/html/box-booking/public чтобы по ссылке рута запускался 
мой сайт не страница apach?
2) И нужно ли устанавливать пакеты nodejs и npm и если да то какой версии ?